# multiApkShadowedActiveApk error deploying via Fastlane, but my version number *is* higher

Tags: android, cordova, apk, fastlane

I'm trying to deploy my app to the Play store as an alpha release using Fastlane and I'm getting this error:

`Google Api Error: multiApkShadowedActiveApk: Version 250012 of this app can not be downloaded by any devices as they will all receive APKs with higher version codes.`

I'm attempting to upload 251002, which *is* higher than 250012.  I'm wondering if the fact that I didn't promote 250012 to prod is causing this.
  250012 was in beta and I uploaded 250022 to alpha and went straight to prod with it.

Uploading to alpha has worked fine in the past, it's just when we skip a beta release (i.e. alpha -> production) that this happens.

So, this error isn't making sense to me, since the version in prod and the version I'm attempting to upload to alpha are *both* higher than 250012.

I'm building like this:

`sh "../node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova build --release android"
    sh "jarsigner -verbose \
                  -sigalg SHA1withRSA \
                  -digestalg SHA1 \
                  -keystore ../#{keystore} \
                  -storepass #{ENV["GOOGLE_KEY_PASS"]} \
                  ../#{project_path}/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk \
                  alias_name"
    sh "zipalign -v 4 \
                 ../#{project_path}/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk \
                 ../#{apk_path}"`

My deploy in Fastfile looks like this:

`supply(
      track: 'alpha',
      package_name: package_name,
      skip_upload_metadata: true,
      skip_upload_images: true,
      skip_upload_screenshots: true,
      apk: apk_path,
      json_key: json_key
    )`

Any t-shooting help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think this is a bug with Google play console API. If you promote a version from Alpha to Production, then you can not upload Alpha builds anymore using the API.
To solve this you have to upload a new version to Alpha using the Google play console and then promote this version to beta.

Comment: I think you're right.  I manually promoted my alpha version to beta and the error no longer occurs.

Anyone know where to look to see if a bug has been logged for this already?